# Boundedness for feasible sets in solving an optimization problem. How to check if the feasible set is bounded?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-optimization, upper-lower-bounds

I am struggling with the concept of boundedness in solving several optimization problems. When I go through the theory I understand what it means. However when I look at an example I am struggling to figure out where to begin from. For example in the following optimisation problem there are two constraints and I am trying to maximize the objective function.

$\max(x,y,z) x + 2y − 3z$;

such that $x^2 − 3xy + z^2 \le 5$;

$4x^2 − 2xy + y^2 + 4xz + 10z^2 = 100$

To figure out if the constraints are bounded I tried to solve the equations and came up with the following bounds

$0 < x \le 6,$

$0 < y \le 10,$

$-\sqrt{5} \le z \le 0.$

I have gotten a feeling these are not right as I think my understanding of how to find the bounds are not clear. It would be much appreciated if I can get some ideas or information on bounds including any resource materials that might help me to better understand the concept.

Thanks.

Comment: Boundedness of the feasible set follows from $$\frac{13}{5}x^2+(x-y)^2+10\left(\frac{x}{5}+z\right)^2=4x^2-2xy+y^2+4xz+z^2=100.$$

Comment: Would it be possible to clarify this please? Thanks

Comment: From the equation in my comment, show that the values of $x$ form a bounded set.  Use this to show boundedness of the values of $y$ and $z$.

Comment: What about the first constraint? thanks

Comment: The first comment is enough to show the boundedness of the feasible set. The intersection of a bounded set with any set is bounded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. is there a way to find the bounds for the three choice variables?